# Transforming panel data in R/Excel

Tags: r, excel

I have following dataset, where WEEK specifies a week in a certain year (W03046 is week 46 in 2003) and MSBRAND stands for the marketshare of a specific brand in the corresponding week:

```
WEEK    MSBRAND1    MSBRAND2    MSBRAND3    
W03046  0.20        0.50        0.30
W03047  0.15        0.55        0.30
W03048  0.25        0.30        0.45
....    ...         ...         ...
```

I want to create the following dataset:

```
WEEK    BRAND    SHARE    weekdummy1 weekdummy2 weekdummy3 branddummy1 branddummy3
1       1        0.20     1          0             0       1           0
1       2        0.50     1          0             0       0           1
1       3        0.30     1          0             0       0           0
2       1        0.15     0          1             0       1           0
2       2        0.55     0          1             0       0           1
2       3        0.30     0          1             0       0           0
3       1        0.25     0          0             1       1           0
3       2        0.30     0          0             1       0           1
3       3        0.45     0          0             1       0           0
```

Does anyone have a clue on how I can get from the first dataset to the second one? Either in R or in Excel.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses `melt` from "reshape2", and then a little bit extra from "data.table":

#### Step 1: Making the data long

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
DT <- as.data.table(mydf)
DTL <- melt(DT, id.vars = "WEEK", 
            variable.name = "brand",
            value.name = "share")
DTL[, `:=`(dummy = 1, 
           brand = gsub("MSBRAND", "", brand),
           year = substr(WEEK, 2, 3), 
           week = substr(WEEK, 4, 6), 
           WEEK = NULL)]
DTL[, id := 1:nrow(DTL)]
setkey(DTL, id)
```

#### Step 2: Creating the "week" and "brand" dummy tables

```
weekDummy <- setnames(
  dcast.data.table(DTL, id ~ week, value.var = "dummy", fill = 0),
  c("id", paste0("wd", seq_along(unique(DTL$week)))))
    brandDummy <- setnames(
      dcast.data.table(DTL, id ~ brand, value.var = "dummy", fill = 0),
      c("id", paste0("bd", seq_along(unique(DTL$brand)))))
```

#### Step 3: Merging them all together

```
DTL[weekDummy][brandDummy]
#    brand share dummy year week id wd1 wd2 wd3 bd1 bd2 bd3
# 1:     1  0.20     1   03  046  1   1   0   0   1   0   0
# 2:     1  0.15     1   03  047  2   0   1   0   1   0   0
# 3:     1  0.25     1   03  048  3   0   0   1   1   0   0
# 4:     2  0.50     1   03  046  4   1   0   0   0   1   0
# 5:     2  0.55     1   03  047  5   0   1   0   0   1   0
# 6:     2  0.30     1   03  048  6   0   0   1   0   1   0
# 7:     3  0.30     1   03  046  7   1   0   0   0   0   1
# 8:     3  0.30     1   03  047  8   0   1   0   0   0   1
# 9:     3  0.45     1   03  048  9   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

---

In a later version of "data.table", `dcast.data.table` will be able to handle multiple castings in one step. For now, the solution is to create the dummy variables for "week" and "brand" separately and merge them.

---

You may want to also order the results by year and week.

Answer (score 0):

In R you would look into the reshape function where you are going "wide" to "long".  It would look something like the below code (not run)

```
#Let d be your data set and let d$WEEK be of type factor

d$WEEK=as.numeric(d$WEEK) #change to numeric 

new.d = reshape(d,varying=names(d)[2:4],v.names="SHARE",
        timevar="BRAND", times=1:3, direction="long", idvar="WEEK")

new.d=new.d[order(d.new$WEEK,d.new$BRAND,] #re-order
```

This should get you started

For dummy variables see [Generate a dummy-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable-in-r)