# Categorical variable in classification model

Tags: r, machine-learning, dummy-variable

In a classification model, if I want to keep a categorical variable (e.g Gender), I need to create a dummy variable first.

My question is, this new dummy variable (e.g 1=male, 2=female) should be created as numeric vector? I tried to keep that dummy variable as factor (e.g "1","2") but then I tried to feature scale the dataset and it was not working.

So if I keep those dummy variables as numeric vectors and then create the model, is it going to have any negative effect on the model? I am concerned about this because 1 for male and 2 or female is not actually `numeric` values they are just category.

Please help me. 
This question is bothering me for two days. BTW, I use R for machine learning.

Comment: All you should have to do is to have a factor variable and R will automatically create the dummies for you.  Which exact procedure from which package are you using?  You will need to include some code to get a real answer.

Comment: I will apply several classification models to compare the results.For example, for logistic regression I will fitt the model as model <- glm(formula = Purchased ~.,family=binomial,data=training_set).Do i need to add any other parameters?thanks

Comment: Can you please add that to your question.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable