# How to add a column identifying if another column contains a value

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   ID Time           Item
1 S001   P1           1/2/
2 S002   P1       2/10/7/9
3 S003   P1 1/2/4/5/6/10/9
4 S004   P1 1/2/5/6/10/7/9
5 S005   P1     1/2/10/7/9
6 S006   P1      2/5/6/7/9
```

I want to search the 'Item' column, and create a new column where if the Item column contains a 1, then the new column =1 and if the item column doesn't contain a 1, then the new column =0. 
This is similar to the grepl function, but I want it to input 1s and 0s instead of TRUE and FALSE.

That is, my data set will look like this:

```
ID Time           Item         Item1
    1 S001   P1           1/2/    1
    2 S002   P1       2/10/7/9    0
    3 S003   P1 1/2/4/5/6/10/9    1
    4 S004   P1 1/2/5/6/10/7/9    1
    5 S005   P1     1/2/10/7/9    1
    6 S006   P1      2/5/6/7/9    0
```

I want to do this all the way up to ten columns (the idea is to turn the 'Item' column into a matrix of ones and zeros).

```
       ID Time          Item Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 Item6 Item7 
   1 S001   P1           1/2/    1   1    0     0     0     0     0    

   2 S002   P1       2/10/7/9    0   1    0     0     0     0     1     

   3 S003   P1 1/2/4/5/6/10/9    1   1    0     1     1     1     0
```

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% mutate(Item_split = Item) %>% separate_rows(Item_split, convert = TRUE) %>% drop_na(Item_split) %>% mutate(Item_split = paste0('Item', Item_split), i = 1) %>% spread(Item_split, i, fill = 0L)`, though this is mostly a dupe of [Generate a dummy variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11952706/4497050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  separate_rows(Item, convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Value = 1L) %>%
  complete(ID, Time, Item = 1:10, fill = list(Value = 0L)) %>%
  mutate(Item = paste0("Item", Item)) %>%
  spread(Item, Value) %>%
  select(ID, Time, paste0("Item", 1:10))
dat2
# # A tibble: 6 x 12
#   ID    Time  Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 Item6 Item7 Item8 Item9 Item10
#   <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
# 1 S001  P1        1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
# 2 S002  P1        0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     1      1
# 3 S003  P1        1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     1      1
# 4 S004  P1        1     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     1      1
# 5 S005  P1        1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     1      1
# 6 S006  P1        0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     1      0
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   ID Time           Item
1 S001   P1           '1/2'
2 S002   P1       '2/10/7/9'
3 S003   P1 '1/2/4/5/6/10/9'
4 S004   P1 '1/2/5/6/10/7/9'
5 S005   P1     '1/2/10/7/9'
6 S006   P1      '2/5/6/7/9'",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A direct solution is simply to use `str_detect` or the equivalent `grepl` (not as familiar) and then use `as.numeric` to turn `TRUE` into `1` and `FALSE` into `0`. EDIT: added some lookarounds to make the regular expression more robust. `(?<!\\d)1(?!\\d)` now checks to make sure there is not a digit before or after the `1`. However, I think the second approach below is safer.

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
"  ID Time           Item
 S001   P1           1/2/
 S002   P1       2/10/7/9
 S003   P1 1/2/4/5/6/10/9
 S004   P1 1/2/5/6/10/7/9
 S005   P1     1/2/10/7/9
 S006   P1      2/5/6/7/9"
)

tbl %>% mutate(
  Item1 = as.integer(str_detect(Item, "(?<!\\d)1(?!\\d)"))
)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ID    Time  Item           Item1
  <chr> <chr> <chr>          <int>
1 S001  P1    1/2/               1
2 S002  P1    2/10/7/9           1
3 S003  P1    1/2/4/5/6/10/9     1
4 S004  P1    1/2/5/6/10/7/9     1
5 S005  P1    1/2/10/7/9         1
6 S006  P1    2/5/6/7/9          0
```

However, you can also use other `tidyverse` tools to do the end transformation you want. Here we:

1. Use `separate_rows` to place each `Item` onto its own row,
2. Remove the empty rows created by a line ending in `/` with `filter`,
3. Add a presence column with `mutate`,
4. `spread` the rows back out to make the grid of values that you want,
5. Replace the `NA` values with 0.

`spread` will basically turn the values of `Item` into column headings, and then place the values of `presence` as values in those new columns, leaving `NA` in the blanks.

```
tbl %>%
  separate_rows(Item, sep = "/") %>%
  filter(Item != "") %>%
  mutate(present = 1) %>%
  spread(Item, present, sep = "") %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  ID    Time  Item1 Item10 Item2 Item4 Item5 Item6 Item7 Item9
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 S001  P1     1.00   0     1.00  0     0     0     0     0   
2 S002  P1     0      1.00  1.00  0     0     0     1.00  1.00
3 S003  P1     1.00   1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  0     1.00
4 S004  P1     1.00   1.00  1.00  0     1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00
5 S005  P1     1.00   1.00  1.00  0     0     0     1.00  1.00
6 S006  P1     0      0     1.00  0     1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00
```

Comment: You'll need a more complete regex, as the `10` in the second row is getting recognized as a match for `1`