# r - how to add columns dynamically based on numerical values sequences from another column

Tags: r, dataframe

How to add columns dynamically in a dataframe based on numerical values ​​sequences from another column? I want to add `n` columns into a dataframe based on values from another column. What do I have and what do I want to have:

I have this:

```
head(df)
     x  y
[1]  1 ola
[2]  2 ola
[3]  3 ola
[4]  5 ola
[5]  4 ola
[6]  2 ola
[7]  3 ola
[8]  1 ola
[9]  5 ola
[10] 4 ola
[11] 2 ola
[12] 3 ola
[13] 5 ola
[14] 4 ola
[15] 1 ola
[16] 2 ola
[17] 3 ola
[18] 5 ola
[19] 4 ola
[20] 1 ola
[21] 3 ola
[22] 5 ola
[23] 2 ola
[24] 1 ola
[25] 4 ola
[26] 2 ola
```

In my case, I have a dataframe with `18` columns and each columns has `3305708` rows. So, what do I want to do? I want to dynamically add columns based on column values ​​`x`. That is, in this case, add more `5` columns with values `0` and `1`. Like this:

```
head(df)
     x   y   x_1 x_2 x_3  ...
[1]  1  ola   1   0   0   ...
[2]  2  ola   0   1   0   ...
[3]  3  ola   0   0   1   ...
[4]  5  ola   0   0   0   ...
[5]  4  ola   0   0   0   ...
[6]  2  ola   0   1   0   ...
[7]  5  ola   0   0   0   ...
[8]  1  ola   1   0   0   ...
[9]  5  ola   0   0   0   ...
[10] 4  ola   0   0   0   ...
[11] 2  ola   0   1   0   ...
[12] 3  ola   0   0   1   ...
[13] 5  ola   0   0   0   ...
[14] 4  ola   0   0   0   ...
[15] 1  ola   1   0   0   ...
[16] 2  ola   0   1   0   ...
[17] 3  ola   0   0   1   ...
[18] 5  ola   0   0   0   ...
[19] 4  ola   0   0   0   ...
[20] 1  ola   1   0   0   ...
[21] 3  ola   0   0   1   ...
[22] 5  ola   0   0   0   ...
[23] 2  ola   0   1   0   ...
[24] 1  ola   1   0   0   ...
[25] 4  ola   0   0   0   ...
[26] 2  ola   0   1   0   ...
```

How can I do this dynamically? In this case I have just `5` values, but in my case I have columns that has `45` values and I have to add columns the same way I did here. How can I do this?

Comment: [Generate a dummy-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table` on the 'x' column with the sequence of rows and `cbind` with the original dataset

```
res <- cbind(df, as.data.frame.matrix(table(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$x)))
names(res) <-  tolower(make.names(names(res)))
res
#   x   y x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
#1 1 ola  1  0  0  0  0
#2 2 ola  0  1  0  0  0
#3 3 ola  0  0  1  0  0
#4 5 ola  0  0  0  0  1
#5 4 ola  0  0  0  1  0
#6 2 ola  0  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Wow. I don't manage to understand how the table can get this result. Could you explain a bit ?

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. Thank you!!

Comment: @denis In the `table` we are getting the frequency of the 'x' variable with the sequence of rows, and then by using `as.data.frame.matrix`, convert it to a `data.frame` with the similar structure (direclty calling `as.data.frame` on a `table` object will convert it to a 3 column long form dataset) and then `cbind` with the original dataset