# how to subset dataframe based on vector and then group by in dplyr

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
 ID        Blocks
 123       2D
 345       2E
 324       2D
 567       4F
 678       5E
 444       2D
 145       2D
```

Now I want to subset dataframe based on a vector and then on each subset I want to apply group by

e.g    `vec <- c(2,3,2)` Now First it should subset the dataframe with first two rows

```
 df <- df[1:2,]
 df %>%
 group_by(Blocks) %>%
 summarise(count = n())
```

Then it should subset the dataframe with next 3 rows

```
 df <- df[3:5,]
 df %>%
 group_by(Blocks) %>%
 summarise(count = n())
```

and so on. Desired output will be,

```
 Subset    2D    2E     4F     5E
  2         1     1     0      0
  3         1     0     1      1
  2         2     0     0      0
```

Individually I can do with above code,but my dataframe is huge and I have to subset it many times.
How can we do it more effectively in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `rep` to create a grouping variable for `split`ting the dataset into a `list` of 'data.frame', then with `map`, get the `count`

```
library(tidyverse)
split(df, rep(seq_along(vec), vec)) %>% 
              map(~ .x %>%
                      count(Blocks))
```

---

Or another option is to create a column of 'grp' based on 'vec' (to be more aligned with the expected output which is 'wide' dataset., along with 'Subset' that is actual values of 'vec', `summarise` to get the frequency and `spread` the data to 'wide' format

```
df %>%
   filter(row_number() <= sum(vec)) %>% #based on the comments from OP
   mutate(Subset = rep(vec, vec)) %>%
   group_by(grp = rep(seq_along(vec), vec), Blocks) %>%
   summarise(Subset = first(Subset), n = n())%>%
   ungroup %>%
   spread(Blocks, n, fill = 0) %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#   Subset  `2D`  `2E`  `4F`  `5E`
#*  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   2.00  1.00  1.00  0     0   
#2   3.00  1.00  0     1.00  1.00
#3   2.00  2.00  0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks for your  answer. Now my dataframe has `2086` observations and my `vec <- c(32,78,78)` when I run your code it gives me an error. `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) Column Subset` must be length 2086 (the number of rows) or one, not 188`

Comment: @Neil  Here, the vector you showed is having a sum of 7 and the number of rows is 7.  I don't understand the logic for replicating '2086' via 'vec'.  In the comment, the sum for `vec` is 188.  Could you specify the rules.  It seems very vague

Comment: Idea is to subset the rows based on vector specified. e.g I have 100 rows and my `vec <- c(10,10,10)` then only for this rows it will calculate group by. for 1st 10 rows then 11 to 20 and 21:30 likewise.

Comment: What about after 21:30? Let's take your first comment i.e. `vec <- c(32, 78, 78)`  What will be the grouping for 2086?

Comment: After 21:30 it will not run.

Comment: @Neil In that case, first do a subset of the dataset i.e. `df %>% filter(row_number() <= sum(vec)) %>% mutate(..`

Comment: @Neil I updated the post.  Please check if that is what you meant

Comment: Perfect, thats what I needed. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @akrun I found a quite simple solution based on one of your numerous genial answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I have an other answer using an other great idea of akrun here [r - how to add columns dynamically based on numerical values ​sequences from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49111791/r-how-to-add-columns-dynamically-based-on-numerical-values-sequences-from-ano/49111866?noredirect=1#comment85247344_49111866). You then just need to sum over each group created by `rep(seq(vec), vec)`, and the result is quite simple:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(seq(nrow(df)),df$Blocks))
df2 %>%
  group_by(grp = rep(seq(vec), vec)) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)%>%
  mutate(grp=vec)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
    grp  `2D`  `2E`  `4F`  `5E`
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     2     1     1     0     0
2     3     1     0     1     1
3     2     2     0     0     0
```