# how to train a lasso with both text and numeric variables?

Tags: r, classification, tm, text2vec

Consider this modified classic example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

dtrain <- data_frame(text = c("Chinese Beijing Chinese",
                              "Chinese Chinese Shanghai",
                              "France",
                              "Tokyo Japan Chinese"),
                     add_numeric = c(1, 1, 0, 1),
                     doc_id = 1:4,
                     class = c(1, 1, 1, 0))


> dtrain
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  text                     add_numeric doc_id class
  <chr>                          <dbl>  <int> <dbl>
1 Chinese Beijing Chinese            1      1     1
2 Chinese Chinese Shanghai           1      2     1
3 France                             0      3     1
4 Tokyo Japan Chinese                1      4     0
```

Here, I would like to use **lasso** to predict `class`. The variables of interest are `text` and `add_numeric`.

I know how to use `text2vec` or `tm` to predict `class` using `text` only: the packages will transform `text` into a sparse document term matrix and feed the model.

However, here, I want to use both a textual variable `text`, and `add_numeric`. I do not know how to mix the two approaches. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Training your `Lasso` model on `add_numeric` and the dummy variables obtained from `text` does not solve your problem ?
PS : Since `class` is categorical, I would advice you to train a `logistic lasso` model instead of a simple `lasso`.

Comment: yes that is the idea but how to do that in practice? my text has thousands of different words so I need to use a dtm from `text2vec` or others. however, i cannot add my numeric to the `dtm` easily in these packages (theyvare only meant for text)

Comment: So your question is **how to get dummies from a factor variable** ? This question has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable) . It's worth it to go take a look on all the methods offered by R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked how to do this with text2vec, but with quanteda this is quite easy to do, just using `cbind` and the advantage is that is stays a sparse matrix. I haven't changed the dimnames so the added column will be shown as feat1.

```
library(quanteda)

dtm <- dfm(dtrain$text) # create documenttermmatrix
dtm_num <- cbind(dtm, dtrain$add_numeric) # add column to sparse matrix.
dtm_num
Document-feature matrix of: 4 documents, 7 features (60.7% sparse).
4 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    chinese beijing shanghai france tokyo japan feat1
  text1       2       1        0      0     0     0     1
  text2       2       0        1      0     0     0     1
  text3       0       0        0      1     0     0     0
  text4       1       0        0      0     1     1     1
```

Comment: very effective!

Comment: can we feed this to lasso?

Comment: yep, directly. `glmnet(dtm_num, y = dtrain$class)` glmnet doc: x  Can be in sparse matrix format

Comment: hello phiver! `cbind` does not work anymore today... any ideas? thanks

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ, What do you mean it doesn't work anymore? If I use the example above everything works fine. quanteda 2.1.2 and R 4.0.2