# unaggregating , concatenated levels in a factor variable and creating a frequency table

Tags: r, factors

I have a column 'X1' which has concatenated entries which needs to be converted to individual levels and then a frequency table of co-occuring levels

items          x1

ram           [a,b,c ]

pam          [d,e,f]

has to be transformed to

```
items   a   b   c   d   e   f     

ram     1   1   1   0   0   0   

pam     0   0   0   1  1   1
```

pls advise

Comment: Related: [*Generate a dummy-variable*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11952706/2204410)

Comment: Its not same as the link showed by you, my column 'X1' has categories stacked in them- a,b,c,d,e,f each are individual categories for which I would want to create individual dummy columns

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input showed, the values in the second column can be a string.  One option would be to extract the letters from the 'ram' column with `str_extract` (`stringr`), `stack` it to a two column `data.frame`, get the frequency count (`table`) after converting the 'values' column to a `factor` with `levels` specified so that we get 0 for all the levels that are not found in the dataset, reshape it to 'long' format with `as.data.frame`

```
library(stringr)
df2 <- stack(setNames(str_extract_all(df1$ram, '[a-z]'), seq_len(nrow(df1))))[2:1]
out <- as.data.frame(table(df2$ind, factor(df2$values, levels = letters[1:6])))[-1]
names(out) <- names(df1)
out
#   items ram
#1     a   1
#2     b   1
#3     c   1
#4     d   0
#5     e   0
#6     f   0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(items = 'x1', ram = '[a,b,c]', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dummies library:

```
library(dummies)
df <- dummy.data.frame(df, names=c(“MyField1”), sep="_")
```

Note: This splits the original field into number of unique values. The original field is no longer available in data frame.

Example:

Data:

[image]

after

```
df <- dummy.data.frame(df, names=c(“MyField1”), sep="_")
```

[image]

Comment: my column 'X1' has categories stacked in them- a,b,c,d,e,f each are individual categories for which I would want to create individual dummy columns. I need to unstack those categories and then create dummy variables

Comment: Here myfield1 is unstacked according to available categories(A,B,C) and creating individual columns for each category. May be I am unable to follow your question, Please elaborate

Comment: if I take your example- then MyField1 should have entries like (A,B), (B,C,D). (A,C) etc in the 3 records respectively . Then the columns should be populated accordingly where for first entry dummy column A & B would be 1,1 and rest dummy columns would be 0 and so on